# Quadrilateral Thinking: Spell

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle

How should each of the empty spaces be filled?

```
  W P D U
O N   R K
X Q     B
T H S L F
E   J V Y
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The missing letters are:

> **MAGIC**, as we have all the other letters from A to Y (skipping Z)

This clues:

> A [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square), and converting the letters (A1Z26) lets us fill in the grid:
>
> ```
>                               65 
>  A W P D U     1 23 16  4 21| 65
>  O N G R K    15 14  7 18 11| 65
>  X Q M I B    24 17 13  9  2| 65
>  T H S L F    20  8 19 12  6| 65
>  E C J V Y     5  3 10 22 25| 65
>               --------------+
>               65 65 65 65 65  65
> ```

Comment: Correct, and very nice explanation!

Comment: How do I delete my terrible edit?